# memcpy qt and compile error

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function

```
SCalibration(uint8_t number, const ABC::report& report,
                         return* ret)
{
    uint8_t args[2];
    args[0]=number;
    memcpy(&(args[1],&report,sizeof(ABC::report)));
}
```

where report is structure in file ABC with different data types .
When I tried to compile I get the error
"L value requires as unary & operand.

Please help

Comment: Looks like misplaced `()`, although it is not clear your destination is large enough to hold the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
memcpy(&(args[1],&report,sizeof(ABC::report)));
```

Should be

```
memcpy(&(args[1]),&report,sizeof(ABC::report));
```

You should also ensure that `args` is sufficiently large to hold the result.

Comment: This solution will not work since the source is larger than `1 byte` at best this will introduce a segfault at worst it will corrupt data without crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You have some rogue parentheses; it looks like you mean

```
memcpy(&args[1],&report,sizeof(ABC::report));
```

to copy the bytes of `report` into the `args` array.

Now the problem is that this will overflow the array if the report is larger than one byte. Perhaps you want:

```
uint8_t args[1 + sizeof(ABC::report)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a misplaced set of `()`s on this line:

```
memcpy(&(args[1],&report,sizeof(ABC::report)));
```

it looks like you intended:

```
memcpy(&(args[1]),&report,sizeof(ABC::report));
```

My next observation is that your destination is only `1 byte` is your source `report` only `1 byte` in size? If not your have a overflow which is undefined behavior. One solution would be to adjust the size of `args` by the size of your data:

```
uint8_t args[sizeof(ABC::report)+1];
```

Comment: my source report has the size of approximately 100 bytes.

Comment: That will not work, you need to add the sizeof(ABC::report) to your array size or something similar.